# This program is not \n terminating and keep taking input

Tags: c++, arrays, char, newline, cin

This program is not \n terminating and keep taking input until the size of array is specified in condition is not reached.This program should terminate when \n is encounterd.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    int size = 20;
    char firstName[size];
    char c = '0';       
    int i=0;
    cout<<"Enter Name : ";
            while(c != '\n' && i < size)
            {
                cin>>c;
                cout<<i<<endl;
                firstName[i] = c;
                i++;
            }
            firstName[i-1]='\0';
            cout<<"Output : ";
    puts(firstName);

    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting that this program take input without any problem and give me output as expected without any hasal.

Comment: There are a few issues. In C++ for strings do NOT use "C" style arrays (like firstName, who taught you this?) but use std::string. Further more you try mixing reading a string with reading only one character. You will need something like `std::string firstName; while(firstName.size() == 0) std::cin >> firstName;` to stop at an empty input.  Side note : unlearn to use `using namespace std;`

Comment: You could reduce the linecount by using ```cin.getline( firstName, size );```

Comment: frankly, code looks like you are trying to guess how stuff works. Thats not going to be fun on the long run. Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: A spedific feature for the [operator>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) overloads is that they start each input operation by skipping leading whitespace. This includes non-visible characters like space, tab, and `\n`.

Comment: Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: To read raw characters you could use [`cin.get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get), but that's not really appropriate here. Read an entire string at one shot, as other comments have suggested.